# Importing a google font on freecodecamp.com

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I'm doing the 15th lesson on freecodecamp.com but I cannot seem to complete it. The objective is to make my **h2** element use the font **'Lobster'** while keeping Monospace. I'm supposed to copy,"http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>". Here is the code I wrote:

```
<style>
  .red-text {
    color: red;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Monospace;
  }
</style>

<style>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</style>

<h2 class='red-text'>CatPhotoApp</h2>

<p class='red-text'>Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff.</p>
<p class='red-text'>Purr jump eat the grass rip the couch scratched sunbathe, shed everywhere rip the couch sleep in the sink fluffy fur catnip scratched.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style>
       .red-text {
       color: red;
       }

     p {
         font-size: 16px;
         font-family: Monospace;
       }

    h2 { 
         font-size: 16px;
         font-family: Lobster; 
       }
  </style>
</head> 

    <h2 class="red-text";>CatPhotoApp</h2>

    <p class="red-text">Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff.</p>

    <p class="red-text">Purr jump eat the grass rip the couch scratched sunbathe, shed everywhere rip the couch sleep in the sink fluffy fur catnip scratched.</p>
```

The above code help me get to the next step. I had initially put the call for the lobster font in the CSS style, oops! Finally I found this site and the following link (https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) to help me realize that I needed to create a head before the style and put the call in there (head), copied and pasted from the instructions of course.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **'Lobster'** as font-family:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
 .red-text {
   color: red;
  }

h2 {
   font-family: 'Lobster';
}

 p {
   font-size: 16px;
   font-family: monospace;
  }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to use Lobster as font-family:

```
h2 {
    font-family: Lobster;
}
```

Comment: How does this make the `H2` element use `Lobster`?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of issues with the snippet you put as well:

1. `<link>` tag seats in the `<head>` and not in the `<style>` tag.
2. Its best to put the `<style>` tag itself in the `<head>` tag

here is a sample :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <style>
            .red-text {
                color: red;
            }

            p {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: Monospace;
            }

            h2 {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: Lobster;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2 class='red-text'>CatPhotoApp</h2>

        <p class='red-text'>Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the
            red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff.</p>

        <p class='red-text'>Purr jump eat the grass rip the couch scratched sunbathe, shed everywhere rip the couch sleep in the
            sink fluffy fur catnip scratched.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this make the `H2` element use `Lobster`?

Comment: You are right @Bond, i missed the h2 bit ;) going to include it in the sample. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
style>
  .red-text {
    color: red;

  } 

  h2 { font-family : Lobster}

   p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Monospace;
  }
</style>
```

This is correct answer